# Ionic 5 ERR_AVD_HOME_NOT_FOUND: No valid Android AVD home found. in WIndows 10

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator, ionic4

I created an ionic 5 blank app and tried to run it on android emulator as the given instructions in the documentation by running `ionic cordova run android -l`

Ionic version 5.2.7

Cordova version 9.0.0

Gradle version 5.6.2

Native run version 0.2.8

ANDROID_HOME: D:\Android\sdk

**PATH:**

%ANDROID_HOME%\tools

%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin

%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator

Emulator also running

**Console error -**

```
> cordova.cmd build android --emulator
[INFO] ... and 78 additional chunks
[ng] i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk --virtual --forward 8100:8100
[native-run] ERR_AVD_HOME_NOT_FOUND: No valid Android AVD home found.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

        native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native-run couldn't find the AVD HOME, just create a new directory under -

> C:\users\%USERNAME%\ ->.android\avd

If this doesn't work add it to your **$PATH** variable.